# Robot Framework AutoitLibrary run command does not fail but does not open the application

Tags: autoit, robotframework

I am having an issue that notepad.exe is not getting opened. The run command itself is successful according to the log. But Nothing is opening. I have just installed AutoItLibrary with pip and downloaded and installed Autoit on my machine. My path is only to Python and Python Scripts directory. I have no other components running. Do I have to have any other thing done? have the code Library|AutoitLibrary |Run|notepad.exe |Send|'abc' Send fails saying no such keyword found. I do not see the notepad opening at any point. I also tried wait for the window where it just waits until time out and comes out without the notepad getting opened.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. A Pip install is not doing the full job. I had to download the distro zip file and run the setup install.