# Robot framework AutoIt library showing no error, but not starting the application

Tags: robotframework, autoit

Applications such as notepad or wordpad is not getting opened by the run command even after giving the entire path. The calculator is getting opened but no other program is getting opened. AutoIt is installed and working fine in my system. Program for calculator is also working fine, but no other applications seem to start.
All of the runs show the test as pass though even if the application is not up.

I already tried full path and I tried another answer at [Robot Framework AutoitLibrary run command does not fail but does not open the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887401/robot-framework-autoitlibrary-run-command-does-not-fail-but-does-not-open-the-ap)

```
Run_Program
    RUN   SnippingTool.exe
```

Comment: If you are running a x64 system with a x86 process then `SnippingTool.exe` may not be found, as it only exist in x64 PATH. If `notepad.exe` does not run, then you have another issue, as `notepad.exe` is in x86 PATH and x64 PATH.

Comment: @michael_heath: Both notepad and snipping tool doesnt run. Nothing else runs but calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `Run` method is implicitly applying the `SW_HIDE` for
the `Flag` argument, in **AutoItX**.

In **AutoIt**, if you use the `Default` keyword, as the flag argument
in the `Run` function, it hides the startup window using the flag of
`SW_HIDE`.
`SW_HIDE` is the default in **AutoItX** as well, as my testing shows.

So what appears to be result is that `calc.exe` ignores the `SW_HIDE`
flag at startup while other programs such as `notepad.exe` may apply
it. The programs do start and you can see in the *Task Manager*
that they are running, yet the windows may be in a hidden state.

This is the test file opened with a Python X64 process:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SW_MAXIMIZE}      3
${SW_SHOW}          5
${SW_MINIMIZE}      6
${SW_SHOWDEFAULT}  10

*** Test Cases ***
Run_Program
    Run   notepad.exe  ${EMPTY}  ${SW_SHOW}
    Wait For Active Window   Untitled - Notepad
    Send   Welcome To AutoIt!   1
```

The window of Notepad does show.

I am not sure if constants are already available, so I added some
variables for use as the `Flag` argument of `Run`. All of the
variables tested OK in testing the startup window state.

Note that the [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) can affect paths on a x64 OS.
A 32 bit process for i.e. can be redirected to `SysWOW64` directory,
instead of the `System32` directory. On a x64 OS, `SnippingTool.exe`
is in `System32` for a x64 process to access, though is not in `SysWOW64`
for a redirected x86 process. `SysNative` is an alias that can avoid the
redirection of the x86 process.

I am not aware `wordpad.exe` is in the OS `PATH` variable so you may need
to use a full path to access. `Run` with argument of only `wordpad.exe`
fails the test.

Comment: Thank you Michael! It worked! The documentation didnt say anything about the flag. However I now has another issue in send. send  Welcome To Autoit! is not getting sent to the notepad window, but i am getting it as output in pycharm. Why is that? The keywords passed as well

Comment: You need to wait for the window to appear, before using `Send`. View keyword `Wait For Active Window` in `C:\RobotFramework\Extensions\AutoItLibrary\AutoItLibrary.html`.